# Como funciona o construtor padrão do Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método, construtor

Como é o construtor padrão Java? É esse?

```
public Pessoa(){
    super();
}
```

Comment: O padrão vem implicitamente (mesmo sem criares), mas assim como fizeste é explícito. O `super();` não é obrigatório.

Comment: mas se eu não colocar nada ele já coloca para mim direto né? para eu poder herdar o construtor da classe Object da java.lang, correto?

Comment: Não, elas podem ser invocadas como fizeste, mas não o são implicitamente. Só pra reforçar http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: @Leonardo estava pensando uma coisa, no fundo você tem duas perguntas em uma, você poderia separá-las? Deixa a do construtor aqui e passe a da assinatura para uma pergunta nova. Nós procuramos manter as perguntas de forma bem organizada para ajudar outras pessoas no futuro e o ideal é que não misturasse dois assuntos que apesar de estarem próximos, não é sobre a mesma coisa.

Comment: Eu separei a pergunta da assinatura já que ela é bem diferente da parte sobre construtor. A [nova pergunta pode ser encontrada aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

Comment: @Leonardo Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10):

O construtor padrão (*default constructor*) é aquele que o compilador cria para você. Se você criar, ele não é o padrão. Você pode até simular um igual ao *default*:

```
public Pessoa() { super(); }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Super2.java).

Essa é a forma que um *default constructor* é montado para você quando você não o cria. O *default constructor* nunca tem parâmetros e tem nada no corpo a não ser uma referência à classe superior. Ele existe apenas para iniciar a criação do objeto, ele faz nada.

Na verdade [a chamada do `super()` neste caso é desnecessária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108453/101). Veja também: [Qual a função do super em um construtor em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45028/101).

Está na [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).

[Mais sobre construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Comment: Beleza, mas o Default constructor contem o super() de forma implicita né?

Comment: @bigown, consegues explicar melhor a segunda pergunta dele (@Leonardo)? Pois se percebi bem a sequência é nome + quantidade de parametros+tipo, e isso é confuso pra mim. Se der, manda ai um exemplo.

Comment: @Leonardo Estou concluindo a resposta. Cold, melhorarei.

Comment: Isso ai é mesmo já uma alinha neh @bigown? :). Embora eu ache que deveria focar muito mais na questão dos construtores.

Comment: @Cold acabei de sugerir ao AP.

Comment: Ok. Quanto a questão de dizer que "nome + quantidade de parametros +tipo dos parametros"? Eu nao percebi bem a ideia nisso. O que representaria a quantidade de parâmetros?

Comment: Uma pequena complementação: se você declarar um construtor com argumentos na classe, o Java não adiciona o construtor padrão. Se quiser que além do construtor com argumentos haja um sem argumentos, você terá que adicionar este último explicitamente.