# Qual a função do super() em um construtor em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, construtor

Tenho uma classe filha que herda de outra classe abstrata, e o no construtor da classe tenho o seguinte:

```
Public aluno(String nome, int idade){
    super(nome,idade);
}
```

Qual a função do "super" no construtor da classe?

Comment: Ele chama o construtor da classe que você está herdando.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Serve para chamar o construtor da classe mãe. Se esta classe é composta pelo menos em parte por outra classe herdada, esta parte também precisa ser inicializada e este é um jeito de inicializar os dados da classe mãe.

Vamos pensar que a classe seria:

```
class Aluno extends Pessoa
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Extends.java).

Então o `super` está chamando um construtor da classe `Pessoa` que tenha a assinatura adequada para receber o nome e idade da pessoa que foi obtido através do construtor de `Aluno`.

Answer (score -5):

Quando temos objetos e fazemos que uma classe herde as características de outra,
usando "extends", é necessário criarmos os construtores, porém muitos deles por questão
de elegância se definem com o mesmo nome da classe pai ou superclasse, então para podermos
diferenciar ao que nos referimos, usamos "this" para a subclasse e "super" para a superclasse.

Comment: Ou você não entendeu a pergunta ou não sabe como isso funciona.

Comment: Não é necessário criar construtores, criamos somente se quisermos/precisarmos. Em Java, não é questão de elegância, é uma exigência da sintaxe da linguagem que o construtor use o mesmo nome da classe (da *própria classe*, não da superclasse). E sua última frase se aplica mais a campos/métodos do que a construtores (de fato, usamos `this` para se referir a membros da própria classe, e `super` para membros da superclasse - inclusive métodos sobrescritos). Para se invocar explicitamente um construtor específico da superclasse (em vez de implicitamente o construtor padrão) é obrigatório o `super`.