# Construtor vazio sem chamar super()

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, construtor, java-bean

Quando faço construtores parametrizados crio um construtor também vazio.

No construtor vazio, devo sempre fazer a chamada a super()? Por que?

Leve em consideração, que minha classe é apenas um JavaBean.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45028/101

Comment: @bigown Essa parte eu entendo (quando tem-se sub-classes e superclasses). A minha dúvida é em relação a um JavaBean que não herda de outra classe. Que por padrão, herda de Objects. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu editei a minha resposta porque eu comecei ela certo, mas quando fui justificar foi por um caminho intuitivo mas que não reflete a realidade do Java. A resposta estava correta, mas por linhas tortas. Vendo a resposta do utluiz me dei conta disto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É sempre necessário inicializar a instância com a construção do objeto integralmente, ou seja, a parte da [classe superior precisa ser construída, e por isso tem que chamar o `super()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45028/101). Se isso não for feito explicitamente no construtor o compilador faz por você, mesmo para o `Objects`. Só precisa fazer manualmente se tiver um motivo, um deles é quando a classe mãe não tem um construtor padrão.

Especificamente esse ponto independe de ser Beans ou não, Beans tem outros requerimentos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma das convenções do JavaBean é utilizar um construtor vazio. Por isso, utilizei ele para exemplificação.

Do mesmo modo, tirasse minha dúvida. "Objects não precisa de construção."

Obrigado!

Comment: Sim, eu sei, é um requisito dele mesmo. E pelo que está na pergunta, acho que entendeu que só em alguns casos precisa criar o construtor sem parâmetros. Ele pode ser criado automaticamente se não criar outro construtores.

Comment: Geralmente utilizo `super()` somente quando a classe-pai precisa receber um parâmetro, diferenciado ou não. Acontece muito isso em AS3 ao criar classes que herdam de `Event`. No restante, eu nem me preocupo em colocar `super()`.

Answer (score 6):

Em Java, toda classe necessariamente precisa chamar um construtor de sua superclasse, sendo este o primeiro comando dentro do construtor.

Mesmo que uma classe não estenda nenhuma outra classe diretamente, então o `super()` de `Object` será chamado de qualquer forma.

O que confunde um pouco quem ainda não estudou esse conceito é que quando você não chama explicitamente o `super()` em um construtor, o compilador Java adiciona implicitamente uma chamada ao construtor da superclasse sem parâmetros.

Isso ocorre da mesma forma que o compilador também adiciona um construtor padrão, sem parâmetros, quando você não declara nenhum construtor explicitamente.

Se a superclasse não tiver um construtor sem parâmetros, então o compilador obriga você a chamar algum dos construtores usando o `super`.