# Como se chama essa parte do código?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, construtor

Digamos que eu crie uma classe...

```
    public class Teste1 {

        public void Teste1(){
            System.out.println("Olá");
        }

        public void teste2(){
            System.out.println("Oi");
        }

    }
```

O `Teste1` é o método construtor da classe.

E como é chamado o `Teste2`? Também é um método construtor? Que nome se dá para essa parte do código (`Teste2`)?

Comment: É apenas um método comum, nada demais. E `Teste1` não é construtor, pois construtores não tem retorno. A unica coisa diferente é que você não está seguindo a regra de nomes de métodos serem CamelCase, e iniciar com letra minuscula.

Comment: Então estou entendendo tudo errado mesmo rs

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Método. Só isto. Especificamente é um método de instância, mas normalmente não precisamos especificar de forma completa.

O construtor é apenas o que tem o mesmo nome da classe e não possui retorno, e que em tese deveria construir alguma coisa, ou seja atribuir valores para os atributos da classe ou fazer algo na inicialização. Portanto não existe construtores na sua classe, pelo menos não explicitamente. Até existe um [construtor implícito padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34685/101).

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Teste1 teste = new Teste1(); //criando a classe com um construtor implícito
        System.out.println("Criou a classe");
        teste.Teste1(); //está chamando o método normal declarado
    }
}

class Teste1 {
    public void Teste1() { //este método não é um construtor
        System.out.println("Olá");
    }

    public void Teste2() {
        System.out.println("Oi");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/w3ib6q). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tvjxgprm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/MethodSameNameClasse.java).