# Erro de compilação por falta de construtor

Tags: c#, .net, construtor

Tenho as seguintes classes:

classe `Disciplina`:

```
public class Disciplina
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

interface `IGenericaDAO`:

```
public interface IGenericaDAO<T>
{
    bool Add(T e);
    bool Update(T e);
    bool Delete(T e);
    List<T> GetAll();
    T Get(int id);
}
```

interface `IDisciplinaDAO`:

```
public interface IDisciplinaDAO : IGenericaDAO<Disciplina>
{
}
```

classe `GenericaDAO`:

```
public class GenericaDAO<T> : IGenericaDAO<T> where T : class
{
    internal ApplicationDbContext Context  { get; set; }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public GenericaDAO()
    {
        Context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public bool Add(T e)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Added;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public bool Update(T e)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public bool Delete(T e)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

classe `DisciplinaDAO`:

```
public class DisciplinaDAO : GenericaDAO<Disciplina>, IDisciplinaDAO
{
}
```

interface `IGenericaBLO`:

```
public interface IGenericaBLO<T>
{
    bool Add(T e);
    bool Update(T e);
    bool Delete(T e);
    List<T> GetAll();
    T Get(int id);
}

public interface IGenericaBLO<T>
{
    bool Add(T e);
    bool Update(T e);
    bool Delete(T e);
    List<T> GetAll();
    T Get(int id);
}
```

interface `IDisciplinaBLO`:

```
public interface IDisciplinaBLO : IGenericaBLO<Disciplina>
{
}
```

classe `GenericaBLO`:

```
public class GenericaBLO<T> : IGenericaBLO<T> where T : class
{
    private IGenericaDAO<T> dao;

    public GenericaBLO(IGenericaDAO<T> _dao)
    {
        dao = _dao;
    }

    public bool Add(T e)
    {
        bool resultado = dao.Add(e);
        return resultado;
    }

    public bool Update(T e)
    {
        bool resultado = dao.Update(e);
        return resultado;
    }

    public bool Delete(T e)
    {
        bool resultado = dao.Delete(e);
        return resultado;
    }

    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return dao.GetAll();
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return dao.Get(id);
    }
}
```

classe `DisciplinaBLO`:

```
public class DisciplinaBLO : GenericaBLO<Disciplina>, IDisciplinaBLO
{}
```

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro de compilação na classe `DisciplinaBLO`:

> Error 1   'Core.BLL.Base.GenericaBLO' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments    DisciplinaBLO.cs    12  18  Core

Comment: Tem muita coisa que parece ser repetida ai, edita a pergunta e remova se realmente for.

Comment: Olá, não me parece ter algo repetido não. Coloquei todas as classes e interfaces para poder ajudar a achar o erro. Já achei, faltou declarar o construtor da classe GenericaBLO, pois uma vez que você cria um construtor com parâmetros, o construtor default (sem parâmetros) não é criado automaticamente.

Comment: Tem muita coisa ruim neste código. Onde está dando esse erro? Em uma chamada  ou em uma classe que está herdando `GenericaBLO`, certo? Mostre pra gente isso.

Comment: Estou obtendo o seguinte erro de compilação na classe DisciplinaBLO.

Me ajuda, o que está ruim no código?

Comment: @LeandroDuarte E o que tem em `DisciplinaBLO`? Nada? Então porque tem essa classe?

Comment: Porque ela terá uma implementação depois. Estou especializando para reuso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução é simples, adicione isto na classe:

```
public GenericaBLO() {}
```

Como `DisciplinaBLO` herda de `GenericaBLO`, ela precisa chamar um [construtor padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34688/101) da classe base e ele não existe, precisa criar um. O construtor padrão só é criado automaticamente se não for criado nenhum outro construtor.

Entenda [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Quando tiver uma implementação pode ser que tenha solução melhor.

Não gosto nada desses nomes também, mas deve ser apenas eu.

Aproveitei e melhore o estilo e resolva o problema principal deste código:

```
public class GenericaBLO<T> : IGenericaBLO<T> where T : class {
    private IGenericaDAO<T> dao;

    public GenericaBLO() {}
    public GenericaBLO(IGenericaDAO<T> dao) { //se usar C#7 pode fazer igual aos métodos abaixo
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public bool Add(T e) => dao.Add(e);
    public bool Update(T e) => dao.Update(e);
    public bool Delete(T e) => dao.Delete(e);
    public List<T> GetAll() => dao.GetAll();
    public T Get(int id) => dao.Get(id);
}
```

Pra falar a verdade odeio este tipo de arquitetura, criar uma classe só pra delegar para outra quase sempre é um erro, mas esse é um assunto mais amplo.

E também acho que esses métodos não estão sendo úteis retornando um *bool*, só não falo para tirar esse *bool* porque ele provavelmente está certo, o erro é que nunca retorna um falso, e deveria.

Aproveite e resolva o problema na outra classe:

```
public class GenericaDAO<T> : IGenericaDAO<T> where T : class {
    internal ApplicationDbContext Context  { get; set; }
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public GenericaDAO() {
        Context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public bool Add(T e) {
        Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Added;
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Update(T e) {
        Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Delete(T e) {
        Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public List<T> GetAll() => DbSet.ToList();

    public T Get(int id) => DbSet.Find(id);
}
```

Essas capturas de exceção não fazem o menor sentido e até prejudicam o código. Até acho que a exceção é útil (já que a API não tem [uma forma melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)), mas se fizesse isto:

```
public bool Add(T e) {
    try {
        Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Added;
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    } catch (ExceptionMaisEspecica ex) { //isto é importante, não capture Exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

Eu faria assim:

```
public class GenericaDAO<T> : IGenericaDAO<T> where T : class {
    internal ApplicationDbContext Context  { get; set; }
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public GenericaDAO() {
        Context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public bool Add(T e) => ChangeState(e, EntityState.Added);

    public bool Update(T e) => ChangeState(e, EntityState.Modified);

    public bool Delete(T e) => ChangeState(e, EntityState.Deleted);

    public List<T> GetAll() => DbSet.ToList();

    public T Get(int id) => DbSet.Find(id);

    private bool ChangState<T>(T e, EntityStat state) {
        Context.Entry(e).State = state;
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Style.cs).

Odeio essa repetição de código, mas isso é algo subjetivo meu.

Leia e pesquise mais sobre exceções:

- [Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101)
- [Preciso usar o try/catch em toda a cadeia de um processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128763/101)
- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101)

Comment: Valeu, obrigado!