# Por que dar new no atributo da classe?

Tags: java, memória, construtor

Estou saindo do C++ para o Java e gostaria de saber do porque de dar `new` já no atributo da classe?

```
public class ExemploPES2
{
    class y{
        
        int value;
              
    }
    
    
    class x{
        
        private y nova = new y();
             
        
    }
```

Não entendi o porque de eu dar new já no atributo. Serve para chamar qual construtor?

Comment: E porque não daria? É igual C++. Você realmente queria colocar uma classe dentro da outra?

Comment: O que está fazendo parece ser composição, quando um objeto é composto por outro objeto. Neste caso, o objeto interno é criado dentro do externo. Qual seria o código equivalente em C++?

Comment: Aliás, por quê definir classes dentro de uma classe?

Comment: Em Java, só se tem referências a objetos, por isso você precisa dar um new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Não entendi o porque de eu dar `new` já no atributo.

Você não é obrigado a "dar `new`" na declaração do atributo.

A galera faz isso para evitar que exista uma instância com um atributo nulo.
Por exemplo:

```
public class Y {

    public void fazAlgumaCoisa() {
        //implementação
    }
}

public class X {

    private Y nova;
    
    public Y getNova() {
        return nova;
    }
}

public class Z {

    public void chamaMetodoDeY() {
    
        X meuX = new X();
        Y novaDeX = meuX.getNova();
        
        novaDeX.fazAlgumaCoisa(); //Uma NullPointerException é lançada nessa linha
    }
}
```

O "valor padrão" para variáveis de instância/atributos de tipos não primitivos é `null`.

---

### Práticas para evitar esse cenário

Para evitar cenários como esses, são aplicadas soluções como:

**Prática #1**: Instanciar/inicializar os atributos na própria declaração (seu exemplo);

**Prática #2**: Receber uma instância (ou valor) pelo construtor de sua classe:

```
public class Y {

    public void fazAlgumaCoisa() {
        //implementação
    }
}

public class X {

    private Y nova;
    
    public X(Y nova) {
        this.nova = nova;
    }
    
    public Y getNova() {
        return nova;
    }
}

public class Z {

    public void chamaMetodoDeY() {
    
        X meuX = new X();
        Y novaDeX = meuX.getNova();
        
        novaDeX.fazAlgumaCoisa(); //Nenhuma Exception será lançada nessa linha 
        //pois você receberá uma instância de Y pelo construtor
    }
}
```

**Prática #3**: Injeção de dependências:

Esse já é um tópico um pouco mais avançado.

*Injeção de Dependências* significa, basicamente, que algo ou alguém vai "injetar" uma dependência (instância) em seus atributos de forma *automágica*.

Normalmente temos um *Container de Injeção de Dependências* que é o responsável por injetá-las.

Um exemplo famoso é utilizando o framework [Spring](https://spring.io/):

```
public class Y {

    public void fazAlgumaCoisa() {
        //implementação
    }
}

public class X {

    @Autowired //Anotação do Spring que injeta uma instância de Y quando for necessário
    private Y nova;
    
    public Y getNova() {
        return nova;
    }
}

public class Z {

    public void chamaMetodoDeY() {
    
        X meuX = new X();
        Y novaDeX = meuX.getNova();
        
        novaDeX.fazAlgumaCoisa(); //Nenhuma Exception será lançada nessa linha 
        //pois o Spring injetará a instância necessária quando for necessário
    }
}
```

Obs: para que isso funcione são necessárias algumas (um punhado) de configurações prévias.

---

> Serve para chamar qual construtor? (`private Y nova = new Y();`)

O construtor de `Y` é chamado.

Comment: Você respondeu a pergunta... eu não tinha entendido do porque de dar new no próprio atributo da classe, agora compreendi que serve para não declarar atributo nulo.

Answer (score 9):

O principal motivo de usá-lo é igual ao do C++, indicar que uma alocação no *heap* deve ser realizada para suportar aquele objeto, então a variável ali presente receberá um ponteiro para o objeto alocado, como em C++.

Claro que em Java você não tem o ponteiro exposto diretamente e não é possível optar por usar o `new` o u não, se é uma classe, sempre será um tipo por referência. Tão pouco pode personalizar o operador `new` para esta classe.

Em tipos primitivos isto não é necessário porque a alocação é feita dentro da própria classe, ou *stack*, o valor é colocado ali mesmo e não precisa de uma alocação adicional.

Em tese seria possível não ter esse operador já que toda classe precisa dele. Mas não deixa de ser uma informação extra para indicar que está chamando um construtor e não um método qualquer que retorna um objeto, dando mais legibilidade sobre a intenção do código. Infelizmente para a maioria dos programadores Java acabou se tornando só redundante porque poucos observam sobre a alocação e tempo de vida do objeto, ao contrário do que ocorre em C++.

No seu exemplo a variável `y` está sendo declarada como do tipo `y` (péssimo nome, deveria ser maiúsculo, melhor ainda se fosse um nome significativo), e está chamando o seu construtor para inicializá-lo.

Em tese é possível não chamar nada e não inicializar, assim a variável `y` passaria ter o valor `null`, mas nesse exemplo não serviria para muita coisa, ou todo exemplo não serve. Se não inicializar o campo ([não gosto do termo atributo para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) teria que criar um construtor que faça isto ou trabalhar com um membro potencialmente inválido até que de alguma forma ele seja inicializado.

O compilador do Java cria um [construtor padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34685/101) sempre que você não forneça um construtor. Este construtor serve apenas para padronização de chamada da construção.

Em Java só dá para construir um objeto desta forma, não tem sintaxes alternativas como o C++ tem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

O uso do `new` implica na criação de uma instancia para a classe a direita da palavra reservada `new`, sobre qual construtor está sendo chamado nesse caso é o seguinte, no java, quando você não declara nenhum construtor o compilador do Java adiciona um construtor padrão, qual não possui nenhum argumento, no exemplo que você postou o construtor utilizado é o padrão.

Obs: Caso algum construtor seja declarado na classe o construtor padrão da mesma não é mais incluído pelo compilador e caso você queira utiliza-lo vai ter que inclui-lo manualmente na classe, como no código a seguir:

```
class Pessoa {
  String nome;

  public Pessoa() {}

  public Pessoa(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
  }
}
```