# Devemos criar um construtor vazio em Java?

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação, construtor

É uma boa prática sempre declarar um construtor, mesmo que seja vazio, para a classe?

Eu acho desnecessário, pois o compilador cria automaticamente. Já vi pessoas que sempre criam e defendem veemente que é uma má prática não declarar. Qual é o correto?

Comment: não vejo isso necessariamente como uma boa prática, mas em alguns casos, se a classe for acessada via reflection é bem possível que você tenha um comportamento inesperado

Comment: @LucasMiranda pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: eu estava pensando na possibilidade de algum framework acessar a classe através do newInstance(), mas pensando bem não faz sentido mesmo, seria só caso tivesse algum outro construtor na classe

Comment: @LucasMiranda mesmo que não seja declarado explicitamente um construtor, o construtor padrão sempre estará lá, e em casos de reflection ainda assim seria possível acessá-lo utilizando [Class.getConstructor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) e em seguida chamar o [Constructor.newInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não faz sentido. Você sabe exatamente o motivo porque não faz sentido. O que você ganha fazendo o que o compilador já faz por você exatamente igual?

Na verdade eu vou mais longe, em grande parte dos casos faz sentido criar outros construtores, o que desarma essa habilidade do compilador de criar um [construtor padrão](https://medium.com/better-programming/4-reasons-why-you-should-build-your-own-component-library-73a4e6562793) ([o nome desse mecanismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34685/101)), o que nesse caso se precisar de um teria que criar manualmente. Mas na prática quase sempre que fizer isso deve ter alguma coisa errada, quase sempre não precisa e não deve ter o construtor padrão, nem gerado pelo compilador.

O construtor padrão existe porque não pode ficar sem um, mas ele costuma ser um erro em aplicações robustas. Claro que existem situações que realmente não há motivos para criar algo mais complexo, um caso típico é um objeto anêmico.

Obviamente que **se** faz sentido ter um construtor padrão (sem parâmetros) e ele **precisa ter alguma lógica** dentro que não é vazia ou só para inicializar os membros do objeto (é isso que o construtor que o compilador gera faz), então aí faz sentido criar esse construtor.

Tem uma pergunta sobre [a importância do construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Boa parte das classes criadas que não tem um construtor com parâmetros devem estar erradas, ainda que funcionem. Só está certo se sempre quer a inicialização com os valores padrões de cada tipo dos membros do objeto.

Quando alguém defende algo peça para a pessoa explicar o porquê, e aí pode confrontar com outras pessoas com mais detalhes. Se não tem o porquê, ignore, pode até ser certo, mas sem saber porque não tem motivo para fazê-lo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu vejo que geralmente as pessoas que falam sobre sempre criar um construtor são as mesmas pessoas que criam getters e setters sem real motivo e sem ao menos pensar se será necessário ou útil, vai apenas no automático da IDE criar tudo sem questionar a real necessidade de cada coisa

Comment: @nullptr exatamente! As pessoas decorar regras, mas não aprendem o porquê. Quanto menos API melhor, só crie o que será útil. E por isso quase sempre o construtor padrão até criado pelo compilador não é bom em muitos casos. E nem vou entrar na questão da API parecer ser útil e não ser porque entra uma subjetividade maior.